# MP4-format for mobile devices for video.js

Tags: html, video.js

i am using the HTML5-player Video.js in a project. But I have a problem with my mp4-format for mobile devices.

For information: I am using Video.js 4.3

The videos play on all browsers on PCs. But if I want to play it on mobile devices, the video sometimes doesn't start. Are there any restrictions on the mp4-format? Should I use a specific converter (the soucefile is in .flv-format)? Are there some mobile devices which are not compatibel with video.js? I am using iPhone 5s, Nexus5, Lumia 520, iPad Mini 2 and Nexus7.

Thanks for helping,
Wuz

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the anwser. It was the certificate on our server. We tested it on a server without the certificate, so the Apple-devices can not play the videos. With the certificate all was fine :)